# Using jmx and jconsole for Solr in Windows

Tags: java, solr, jmx

In solr wiki (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Using+JMX+with+Solr) there are informations on how to run Solr with JMX enabled, but it does not work for my windows dev box.

I'm using solr 5.3.1 and even if I start techproduct example (with *bin/solr -e techproducts -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote*) instance of solr does not show up in jconsole.

I'm able to connect to solrmeter and even to elasticsearch node started locally, but not on local solr instance. The only local processes listed by JConsole is SolrMeter and elasticsearch.

Any idea of what is missing?

Answer (score 0):

In the Solr PDF reference guide 6.1 page 547 (CTRL-F jconsole) I found the solution:

```
ENABLE_REMOTE_JMX_OPTS=true
RMI_PORT=18983
```

In Jconsole use chose `remote process` and add `localhost:18983`. The click the "insecure connection".

Answer (score 0):

very easy 
vi solr-5.1.0/bin/solr.in.sh , add follow content into sh :

```
SOLR_HOST="192.168.1.188"  
ENABLE_REMOTE_JMX_OPTS="true"  
RMI_PORT=18983
```

restart solr , you can use jconsole connect it in windows . enjoy it !